# Error: Control reaches end of non-void function. Cant find where to fix the error

Tags: c++

I cannot find the error, the error is located with the function *(calculation findCalculations)*.

This is where the code seems to be having the problems.

**START**

```
calculation findCalculations(float A[][5], int rows) {
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
            cout << endl;
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                sum = sum + A[x][y];

            }
        }
        cout << "Average graylevel: " << sum << endl;

        double min = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                if (A[x][y] < min) {
                    min = A[x][y];
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Min graylevel: " << min << endl;
        int graylevel = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                if (A[x][y] >= .75) {
                    graylevel = A[x][y];
                }
            }
            cout << "Number of bright pixels: " << graylevel << endl;
        }
        bool bright = true;
        bool dark = false;
        for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                if (A[x][y] < .5) {
                    bright = A[x][y];
                }
                if (A[x][y] >= .5) {
                    dark = A[x][y];
                }
            }
            if (dark < bright) {
                cout << "Image has more bright pixels: yes" << endl;

            } else if (dark == bright) {
                cout << "Image has more bright pixels: they have the same" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Image has more bright pixels: no" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**STOP**

If anyone could possibly help me out to figure out what is going wrong that would mean a lot thanks.

Comment: Since the return type of the function isn't `void`you need to return a `calculation`object from it, or declare the funtion `void` - meaning it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Also, searching for `Control reaches end of non-void function` here on Stack Overflow returns 505 hits. Please use the search function before you ask (and consider looking at the duplicate suggestions that popped up when you wrote the question in the first place).

Comment: possible duplicate of [I keep Getting Control reaches end of non-void function. What am I doing wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562545/i-keep-getting-control-reaches-end-of-non-void-function-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Answer (score 2):

You are telling the compiler in the function signature

```
calculation findCalculations(float A[][5], int rows)
```

that the function is returning a `calculation` object. But you have no return statement in your function that actually does that. You are just outputting stuff via `cout`. If you don't actually *need* to return anything from the function, you should change the function signature to

```
void findCalculations(float A[][5], int rows)
```

indicating this to the compiler. If the code calling this function actually expects `calculation` objects, you will have to create and return them at some in the function via a `return` statement.

Comment: Even though im using a structure for this?

Comment: @jayden How could anyone know that you're using a struct? And it does not matter; you either have to return an object of the `calculation`type, or declare the function void.

Comment: What do you mean, you are "using a structure". For what? Do you mean the return type "calculation" is a structure? Even if it was just an int, you would have to return one. Where do you think the program should get the information from to build the return value? I think you have a conceptual problem, but I don't really know how to help you solve it.